# Sending REST Call to Google Cloud PHPMyAdmin Server not working?

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

I have successfully deployed a `phpMyAdmin` server on `Google Cloud` by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine). I am having trouble trying to write to a database that I made in *phpMyAdmin*. I am trying to create a Notification Service based on the new `Firebase Cloud Messaging` that Google has released.

NotificationInstanceService.java

```
public class NotificationInstanceService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationInstance";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        //Displaying token on logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        //Create the request body
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder().add("Token", token).build();
        //Know where to send the request to
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("<db link>.appspot.com/fcm/register.php")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        //Create
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And I deployed, on `https://<db link>.appspot.com`, a file under /fcm/register.php which looks like so:

register.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["Token"])) {

           $_uv_Token=$_POST["Token"];
           $conn = mysqli_connect("<db link>.appspot.com","root","","fcm") or die("Error connecting");
           $q="INSERT INTO users (Token) VALUES ( '$_uv_Token') "
              ." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Token = '$_uv_Token';";

      mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      mysqli_close($conn);
    }
 ?>
```

I am confused because I don't seem to be writing anything to my database called users which I know I already created in the `MySQL` server created on *phpMyAdmin*. I know that the user name and password are also already set on `register.php.` Is there any way I can debug whether or not my script is actually going into the PHP code? How can I debug the PHP code? I also that the Request is actually being built as I can debug through that part of the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Some files that may be helpful that I created when trying to deploy my server:

app.yaml:

```
application: <app server url>
service: default
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
version: alpha-001

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: register.php
  login: admin
```

config.inc.php:

```
<?php 
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '<Secret>'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

// Change this to use the project and instance that you've created.
$host = '/cloudsql/<app server url>:us-central1:<database name>-app-php';
$type = 'socket';

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = $host;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = $type;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
// [END all]
```

php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_uname, getmypid"
```

EDIT: Text when in browser, going to .appspot.com/fcm/register.php

> array(11) { ["pmaCookieVer"]=> string(1) "5" ["pma_lang"]=> string(2)
>   "en" ["pma_collation_connection"]=> string(15) "utf8_unicode_ci"
>   ["pma_console_height"]=> string(2) "92" ["SACSID"]=> string(355)
>   "~AJKiYcFgym76QZfbMX35ddCTdKKf-O7q5koLvNZ0coWTMvw9aNlR5fusNyLRzFyw5DB_t2ygVuTEjHwgrgBco4-wr_V3Eer_Mf0CDuGX2e4IpirCNeiGxkRvaLgRPPyZNZWKUx1mF_DChjsksTirkY5WCzlA3G3MO9bBScrLw8kNOFGnvzkev3-B2x31s_TmnDN5aJ0G3-nPueI4FPpKaaMlPsITziccvXMpiehglQOKoo1Bol3EZSF1tjI9QoJuc-6X_sHgJ0IEppg7K-cBapaEx5CmDD2kWOggnVPWnGj1SiKFUnE3DZD46bjovf5me7IdwfVX22bv5D2PJDPQEN4m3D7yP3-Wdg"
>   ["pma_console_config"]=> string(103)
>   "{"alwaysExpand":false,"startHistory":false,"currentQuery":true,"enterExecutes":false,"darkTheme":false}"
>   ["pma_console_mode"]=> string(4) "show" ["phpMyAdmin"]=> string(40)
>   "cfd814e10982d138c7ed4a3ef510c454c0e5f9b9" ["pma_iv-1"]=> string(24)
>   "bSPnJOOBe5x0iXPbbU5Nww==" ["pmaUser-1"]=> string(24)
>   "oHSLKZ7q6eOaXJ475Q6tzw==" ["pmaPass-1"]=> string(24)
>   "dwKZ9gQPCoe/Uk4sWS4s2g==" }

new register.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST["Token"])) {

           $_uv_Token=$_REQUEST["Token"];
           $conn = mysqli_connect("/cloudsql/<Database ServerURL>","root","","FCM") or die("Error connecting");
           $q="INSERT INTO users (Token) VALUES ( '$_uv_Token') "
              ." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Token = '$_uv_Token';";
      var_dump(mysqli_query($conn,$q));
      mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      mysqli_close($conn);
    } else {
        var_dump($_REQUEST);
    }
 ?>
```

NotificationInstanceService.java

New POST Request:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("<Application Server>/fcm/register.php?Token=123")
            .post(body)
            .build();
```

Comment: if you add a `else { var_dump($_REQUEST); }` to the register.php file just before `?>` do you get any output? If not try replacing the line starting with `mysqli_query($conn,$q)` with `var_dump(mysqli_query($conn,$q));` and try again just for another test.

Comment: @Hafenkranich so where is this being dumped to? I tried to follow your suggestion but can't seem to figure out where I can find more information about the request or anything.

Comment: 1. If you call `https://<db link>.appspot.com/fcm/register.php` inside a browser you should end up inside `else` because you didn't provide a token via POST. I would check if that works first. 2. If that works change all `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` inside register.php and call `https://<db link>.appspot.com/fcm/register.php?Token=123`. That should either send a new fake user to your db or print out useful debug output. 3. If that worked (user in db) the php part seems to work and the problem is somewhere inside your java script. (make sure to reset everything I suggested to change for testing)

Comment: @Hafenkranich thank you so much for your help. The user is not in the DB even after I followed number 2. However, when I call register.php in the browser, (see the original post, my edit), I get this strange string that I'm not sure what to make of. Any ideas what it might mean?

Comment: That gibberish is phpMyAdmin stuff (coming from a cookie). Meaning you ended up inside `else` and nothing got querried to your sql db which is fine. Try calling `https://<db link>.appspot.com/fcm/register.php?Token=123` in a browser. That should output anything the db returns (errors I guess) because with `?Token=123` you should reach the if statement inside `register.php`.

Comment: @Hafenkranich it's interesting, actually the gibberish is indeed what happened when I tried the API call `https://<db link>.appspot.com/fcm/register.php?Token=123`.. so I guess there is an error somewhere trying to connect to the database still using the PHP script?

Comment: ok that would mean the Request.Builder does not send anything after `?`. If you copy-paste the url into a browser/telnet/whatever you still get the same output?

Comment: @user1871869 If the token is not set in the `$_REQUEST` then it looks like a problem with your Java, not your PHP. Can you post a link to the javadoc (or other documentation) of your `Request` class? It's possible that query string parameters need to be concatenated with another chained function, like `.get()` or `.query()`.

Comment: If you just want to test the connection to the DB part (and not the Java query building part) you should be able to just hard-code the token into the PHP file, or supply the token manually in the browser (or [hurl.it](https://hurl.it), or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)) and see what gets returned.

Comment: Thanks @Leith for posting the two API test tool links, really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what exactly is your question, it's not clear. but since you asked: `Is there any way I can debug whether or not my script is actually going into the PHP code? How can I debug the PHP code?` here is your answer:

Change your php code to this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["Token"])) {

           $_uv_Token=$_POST["Token"];
           $conn = mysqli_connect("<db link>.appspot.com","root","","fcm") or die("Error connecting");
           $q="INSERT INTO users (`Token`) VALUES ( `{$_uv_Token}`) "
              ." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Token` = `{$_uv_Token}`;";

      mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      mysqli_close($conn);
    } else {
        echo "Token is not set!";
    }
?>
```

then in `NotificationInstanceService.java` check the response of `OkHttpClient` call:

```
...
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!response.isSuccessful()){
        Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected response"+response.toString());
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "response: "+response.body().string());
    }
...
```